# Why doesn't this async react query function run unless I hit reload or re-expose the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm looking at this code, and am at a loss to explain why "barney 0.5" is only logged on page reload or page re-expose, while barney 0.2 is logged every time as expected.

Anyone?

A side question: If the `enabled` property is a constant boolean value and not a function that returns a boolean, how does react know to re-evaluate the expression for the retry counter?

BTW, I'm using:

```
$ npm list | grep query
below cmd output started 2024 Fri Mar 01 03:31:46 PM PST
+-- @tanstack/react-query-devtools@4.0.10
+-- @tanstack/react-query@4.0.10
```

TIA!

```
const uaq = <
    TQFD = unknown,
    TError = AxiosError,
    TData = TQFD,
    TQK,
    TRD = TQFD
>(
    options: UAQO<
        TQFD,
        TError,
        TData,
        TQK,
        TRD
    >
) => {
    const {
        e = true,
        rc = {},
        trd,
    } = options;
    const { p, q, iv } = useApiPathname(options);
    const {
        il: al,
        data: { at, h: ah } = {},
    } = uaaq();

    console.log(`barney 0: date: ${new Date()}`);
    console.log(`barney 0.1: e: ${e}, al: ${al}, iv: ${iv}`)
    console.log(`barney 0.2: options: ${JSON.stringify(options)}`)

    return useQuery<TQFD, TError, TData, TQK>({
        // Set some default options, which may be overridden
        keepPreviousData: true,
        retry: 3,
        // Get the data
        queryFn: async () => {
            console.log(`barney 0.5: at: ${at}`);

            if (!at) throw new Error('Failed.');

            console.log(`barney 0.6: rc: ${rc}`);

            console.log(`barney 1: date: ${new Date()}`);
            console.log(`barney 2: p: ${p}`);
            console.log(`barney 3: h: : ${JSON.stringify({ ...ah, ...h })}`);
            console.log(`barney 4: trd: ${trd}`);

            // Make the fetch request
            const { h = {} } = rc;
            const { data } = await apiClient.get(p, {
                params: q,
                headers: { ...ah, ...h },
                ...rc,
            });

            console.log(`barney 5: data: ${JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2)}`);

            // Return the data from the response (optionally after transforming it)
            return trd ? trd(data) : data;
        },
        // Apply the other options
        ...options,
        // Wait for values to be filled in....
        enabled: e && !al && iv,
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the queryKey (which is used as an index into a cache) had been set too specifically, so everything was being (inappropriately) satisfied from cache.

Adding the query itself to the end of the queryKey solved the problem.  :)

Answer (score 0):

-> "barney 0.5" is logged inside the queryFn, which is only executed when the query is initially triggered or retried.

-> "barney 0.2" is logged outside the useQuery hook, so it's executed every time the component re-renders.

React Query caches data and re-uses it as much as possible. If the query result is already available and enabled is still true, it won't trigger a re-fetch, hence "barney 0.5" won't be logged again until a re-fetch happens (like on page reload or re-expose).

React evaluates the enabled property whenever any of its dependencies change. Even though enabled is a constant boolean value, its value might depend on other variables or state values that could change. In your case, enabled depends on e, al, and iv, so if any of these values change, React will re-evaluate the expression for the retry counter.

If you want "barney 0.5" to be logged every time useQuery is executed, you may need to adjust your logic or dependencies in the enabled property to ensure it reflects the desired behavior.

Comment: So I'm thinking you're saying that "e && !al && iv" may have a 1 or more variables that aren't from useState() ?

Comment: Yes may be but it is actually dependent on how the query fn is being executed.

Comment: I think how queryFn is used is somewhat outside my control, as it's part of React Query.  I'll look at whether e, al and iv are useState when I'm on the clock tomorrow.

Comment: It looks like none of e, al and iv are from useState.  They're apparently just simple booleans.  I'm still not getting how "e && !al && iv" is re-evaluated by React+Typescript.  It feels like a constant expression, from the perspective of the single useQuery call.  Is `enabled` property magically re-evaluated somehow?

Comment: I get that some of the code is async, so could be deferred until later.  I don't get why queryFn isn't running until a reload or page expose.

Comment: Is it something to do with "e && !al && iv"?  And if so when is that expression evaluated?